# pgo operator failed installing the crunchydata helm

Tags: postgresql, crunchy-postgresql-operator

Trying to install the CrunchyData Postgres operator through the Terraform on the K3s server. I am using the PGO Image Tag: "centos8-4.7.0"
I am getting the following error:

```
TASK [pgo-operator : Create PGClusters CRD] ************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["kubectl", "create", "-f", "/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml"], "delta": "0:00:03.704244", "end": "2022-06-27 06:34:28.810771", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-06-27 06:34:25.106527", "stderr": "error: unable to recognize \"/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml\": no matches for kind \"CustomResourceDefinition\" in version \"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\"", "stderr_lines": ["error: unable to recognize \"/ansible/postgres-operator/roles/pgo-operator/files/crds/pgclusters-crd.yaml\": no matches for kind \"CustomResourceDefinition\" in version \"apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\""], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

### Environment

Please provide the following details:

- Platform:  `Rancher`
- Platform Version:

```
Client Version: v1.24.1+k3s1
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.24.1+k3s1
```

- PGO Image Tag: "centos8-4.7.0"
- Storage:  `nfs`